# Cannot remove the last item in the ListView Flutter

Tags: flutter, listview, flutter-getx

I have a ListView containing the observable list `var cartItems = <CartItem>[].obs;`, when I tried to remove the last item in the ListView, I got error **RangeError (index): Invalid value: Valid value range is empty: 0** and it was undone. Anyone can show me how to fix it? Thanks in advance. This is my code to hold the ListView:

```
return Obx(() {
      if (_cartController.isLoading == false) {
        if (_cartController.cartItems.length == 0) {
          return Center(
            child: Text("Your cart is empty."),
          );
        }
        return Scaffold(
          backgroundColor: Colors.white,
          body: ListView.separated(
            ...
            itemBuilder: (context, index) {
              return Slidable(
                endActionPane: ActionPane(
                  motion: ScrollMotion(),
                  children: [
                    SlidableAction(
                      onPressed: (context) {
                        setState(() {
                          _cartController.cartItems.removeAt(index);
                        });
                        _cartController
                            .removeFromCart(
                                userId: widget.user.id,
                                productId:
                                    _cartController.cartItems[index].item.id)
                            .then((value) {...});
                      },
                      ...
                    ),
                  ],
                ),
                child: GestureDetector(
                  onTap: () => Get.to(() => ProductDetailsScreen(
                      product: _cartController.cartItems[index].item)),
                  child: _itemCard(
                      cartItem: _cartController.cartItems[index], index: index),
                ),
              );
            },
            ...
          ),
          ...
        );
      } else {
        ...
      }
    });
```

Comment: How many items are there in your list?

Comment: @Diwyansh, if the list only has 1 item, I cannot remove this item, if there is more than 1 item I cannot remove the last one. Hope you can help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The issue is with your `onPressed` function.
what does the `removeFromCart` method do? I presume it's calling some api. The problem here is that you are removing the item from `cartItems` array using `removeAt(index)` method. Then you are calling `removeFromCart` method on your controller. And, arguments for that `removeFromCart` method includes
`productId: _cartController.cartItems[index].item.id`.

The error is coming from that line, when item count is 1, here is what your code does:

1. It removes the item at index = 0 on `_cartController.cartItems.removeAt(index);` line.
2. Then proceeds to call to `_cartController.removeFromCart()` which has argument called `productId`. But, now your `cartItems` array is empty - you already removed the item in the previous step. So, it will throw an exception.

Solution: only remove the cartItem at specific index after completing your api call or when that `removeFromCart()` promise full fills.

Comment: thank you so much. at before i wanted to remove quickly because the api was a little slow. thank you so much.